# Incorrect order when using sorted data to plot CategoryChartData in python-pptx

Tags: python, powerpoint, python-pptx

I am trying to plot a graph in decreasing order using python-pptx. Right now, I sort the data in decreasing order, before passing it to the function for plotting. But the chart ends up being reversed(ascending), instead of descending. I'm thinking that `python-pptx` draws the leftmost element in the array first, and subsequent elements gets added to the front of it? How should I change my code?

```
X = ["A", "B", "C"]
y = [91, 32, 10]

if placeholder in paragraph.text:
    paragraph.text = ""
    chart_data = CategoryChartData()
    chart_data.categories = labels
    chart_data.add_series("Series 1", data)
    x, y, cx, cy = Inches(2), Inches(2), Inches(5), Inches(4.5)

    chart_paragraph = cell.paragraphs[i].insert_paragraph_before()
    chart_paragraph.alignment = WD_PARAGRAPH_ALIGNMENT.CENTER

    chart = chart_paragraph.add_run().add_chart(
        XL_CHART_TYPE.COLUMN_CLUSTERED, x, y, cx, cy, 
        chart_data)
```